# Selecting all rows in which id is distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, distinct

Hi i need some advice on how to do a select statement on selecting all rows in which the phone number acts as a measure of "distinction".

Example of what i have.

```
|ID |Name |Phone Number| Address  |
|   |     |            |          |
|1  |John | 1234567    | A.Road 1 |
|1  |John | 1234567    | B.Road 2 |
|2  |Jane | 7654321    | C.Road 3 |
|3  |Jim  | 7654321    | C.road 3 |
```

Example of what i want:

```
|ID |Name |Phone Number| Address  |
|   |     |            |          |
|1  |John | 1234567    | A.Road 1 |
|2  |Jane | 7654321    | C.Road 3 |
```

Regarding on which of the rows SQL chooses to pic on the result doesn't matter only that the whole row is available and that it makes a selection of distinct phone numbers. Hope you understand what i'm trying to do here.

Comment: What is your logic on how you pic name/address?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Probably you need some dbms-specific function, so please specify your target db as @GordonLinoff suggested

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, its done, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSI SQL supports the `row_number()` function, which is a typical solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by phone_number order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Is this supported in Sql Server 2005?

Comment: If sql server 2005 is the databse you use then TAG your question with that so dont waste your time suggesting  things that wont work, or waste our time suggesting them. Check the documentation on row_number  it shows which versions it applies to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Comment: @John . . . SQL Server 2005 was the first version of SQL Server to support `row_number()`.  However, you should be using a supported version of SQL Server.